# Disable alt clicking a tool to cycle through tools in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I use only a few specific tools in photoshop. I frequently `alt` for zooming and color picking, to the point where my finger is always on it and frequently holding it down.

Unfortunately when you alt+click a tool, it cycles through the tools in that tool stack.

This always leads me to picking the wrong tool, and it's happened literally thousands of times.

Please tell me there's a way to disable to extremely annoying "feature".

Comment: Just learn the shortcuts of the tools then you won't have this issue...

Comment: thank you for the terrible suggestion

Comment: ? Why terrible ? Shortcuts are much faster and easier to use compared to clicking the tool in the tool bar.

Comment: because I already have mouse shortcuts for the ones I use most often, and I'm not going to memorize 30 seldom used hotkeys, it's much easier to just click them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option in the Preferences for disabling the Alt+click functionality in tool groups, as far as I know.

You might want to try customizing the toolbar instead. If so, use *Edit > Toolbar*. You can change or remove tool groups in the Cusomize Toolbar dialog. You can click and drag tools out of a group and into the Extra Tools column if you don't need them, or click and drag a tool out of a group, so it's a single item. Obviously if there isn't a group, then Alt will do nothing.

[image]

Comment: can't believe i didn't know about this feature! this is perfect, thank you